# Delete multiple identical values from combo box using array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a value from the combo box dropdown then delete the entire row containing the value across multiple worksheets. Below are what I've managed to find around this forum. What went wrong with this code?

```
Private Sub lstDisplay_Click()

Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(lstDisplay, Sheets("AAA").Range("Dyn_CName"), 0) 'Dyn_CName >> Name Manager
Sheets("Engine").Range("A3").Value = TargetRow

Dim sheetList
sheetList = Array("AAA", "CCC", "EEE")
Dim sheetName
For Each sheetName In sheetList
   DeleteRow ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
Next sheetName
End Sub

Sub DeleteRow(ws As Worksheet)

Dim i As Long, rng As Range

With ws.lstDisplay
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, Sheets("AAA").Rows(i + 1))
            Else
                Set rng = Sheets("AAA").Rows(i + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This post lacks details, e.g. a) What exactly *went wrong* - Error no at which code line (~> Debug code)? b) What is `lstDisplay`, where do you click - describe steps or give an example?  - if it were a userform combobox why do you reference it via `ws.lstDisplay` *"belonging"* to a worksheet?  c) Passing a worksheet name (i.e. as `String` type) as argument to procedure  `DeleteRow` won't work if you declare the same argument as a `Worksheet` object. d) Within the sub you are hardcoding `Sheets("AAA").Rows(i+1)` though it seems that you should replace it by `ws.Rows(i+1)`.

Comment: Hello T.M.
a) The error starts at `Sub DeleteRow(ws As Worksheet)`
b) lstDisplay is from the name of the combo box userform
Thanks.

Comment: The error states Compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: The TargetRow is to find the row of the selected value in combo box - "lstDisplay"

Comment: Try my additions by coding via a CommandButton `..._Click()` event instead in `lstDisplay_Click()` and see if you are getting new error messages.  - The main issues are the incorrect reference of an Userform control via `ws.LstDisplay` instead of correctly `Me.LstDisplay` (assuming your code being in the Userform's code module behind) and that you are hardcoding the rng assignment instead of `Set rng = ws.Rows(i + 1)`.